# Python 3.6: Moving around words within a string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I know that this function moves around characters in a string, as such:

```
def swapping(a, b, c):
    x = list(a)
    x[b], x[c] = x[c], x[b]
    return ''.join(x)
```

Which allows me to do this:

```
swapping('abcde', 1, 3)
'adcbe'
swapping('abcde', 0, 1)
'bacde'
```

But how can I get it to do something like this, so I'm not just moving around letters? This is what I want to accomplish:

```
swapping("Boys and girls left the school.", "boys", "girls")
swapping("Boys and girls left the school.", "GIRLS", "bOYS")
should both have an output: "GIRLS and BOYS left the school." 
# Basically swapping the words that are typed out after writing down a string
```

Comment: @DeepSpace, not really like that...

Comment: What if there are multiple occurence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with regular expressions and a replacement function (could be done with `lambda` and a double ternary but that's not really readable)

Matches all the words (`\w+`) and compares against both words (case-insensitive). If found, return the "opposite" word.

```
import re

def swapping(a,b,c):
    def matchfunc(m):
        g = m.group(1).lower()
        if g == c.lower():
            return b.upper()
        elif g == b.lower():
            return c.upper()
        else:
            return m.group(1)

    return re.sub("(\w+)",matchfunc,a)

print(swapping("Boys and girls left the school.", "boys", "girls"))
print(swapping("Boys and girls left the school.", "GIRLS", "bOYS"))
```

both print: `GIRLS and BOYS left the school.`

Comment: this one gives me the desired outputs, thanks. Quick question: is 're' necessary to produce this output? I haven't quite learned that yet.

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this:

```
def swap(word_string, word1, word2):
    words = word_string.split()
    try:
        idx1 = words.index(word1)
        idx2 = words.index(word2)
        words[idx1], words[idx2] = words[idx2],words[idx1]
    except ValueError:
        pass
    return ' '.join(words)
```

Comment: broad `except:` is bad practice, it's even in the [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations)

Comment: You still have a typo, except is capitalized

Comment: Thanks a ton, @OlivierMelançon my bad. Edited.

Comment: you could `pass` in case of an exception so you'd have only one `return ' '.join` statement, since you're doing it no matter what.

Answer (score 2):

Use `split` function to get a list of words separated by `whitespaces`

```
def swapping(a, b, c):
x = a.split(" ")
x[b], x[c] = x[c], x[b]
return ' '.join(x)
```

If you want to pass strings as parameters use `.index()` to get index of the strings that you want to swap.

```
def swapping(a, b, c):
x = a.split(" ")
index_1 = x.index(b)
index_2 = x.index(c)
x[index_2], x[index_1] = x[index_1], x[index_2]
return ' '.join(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to do two separate things here: swapping and changing character case.

The former has been addressed in other answers.

The later can be done by searching words in a case insensitive manner, but replacing with the input words, keeping cases.

```
def swapping(word_string, word1, word2):
    # Get list of lowercase words
    lower_words = word_string.lower().split()

    try:
        # Get case insensitive index of words
        idx1 = lower_words.index(word1.lower())
        idx2 = lower_words.index(word2.lower())
    except ValueError:
        # Return the same string if a word was not found
        return word_string

    # Replace words with the input words, keeping case
    words = word_string.split()
    words[idx1], words[idx2] = word2, word1

    return ' '.join(words)

swapping("Boys and girls left the school.", "GIRLS", "BOYS")
# Output: 'GIRLS and BOYS left the school.'
```